# constraint validator unique

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

I have this code to do the Unique Validation for data that entered and then input to the base

code entity:

```
    namespace test\MedBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


    /**
     * Apps
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="apps",uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"nom", "prenom","age","class"})}
    )
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="test\MedBundle\Repository\AppsRepository")
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
     * @UniqueEntity(fields={"nom","prenom","class","age"}, message="Cette champ existe déja.")

     */
    class Apps
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $nom;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="class", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $class;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="prenom", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $prenom;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="age", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $age;


          /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
         */
        public $path;

         /**
         * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
         */
        private $file;


       /**
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Med",inversedBy="apps")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_med", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=true)
         */
      private $med;

       /**
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="test\MedBundle\Entity\Affichage",mappedBy="apps")
        */
        private $comment;

       /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
        */

        private $updatedAt;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(name="nbr_modif", type="string", nullable=true)
        */

        private $unbr_modif;


        /**
         * @ORM\PreUpdate
        */
        public function nbremodif() {
            $this->setUnbrModif($this->unbr_modif+1);
        }

       /**
         * @ORM\PreUpdate
        */
        public function updateDate()

          {

            $this->setUpdatedAt(new \Datetime());

          }

          /**
            *@ORM\
          */

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set nom
         *
         * @param string $nom
         * @return Apps
         */
        public function setNom($nom)
        {
            $this->nom = $nom;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get nom
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getNom()
        {
            return $this->nom;
        }

        /**
         * Set prenom
         *
         * @param string $prenom
         * @return Apps
         */
        public function setPrenom($prenom)
        {
            $this->prenom = $prenom;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get prenom
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getPrenom()
        {
            return $this->prenom;
        }

        /**
         * Set age
         *
         * @param string $age
         * @return Apps
         */
        public function setAge($age)
        {
            $this->age = $age;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get age
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getAge()
        {
            return $this->age;
        }

        /**
         * Set class
         *
         * @param string $class
         * @return Apps
         */
        public function setClass($class)
        {
            $this->class = $class;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get class
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getClass()
        {
            return $this->class;
        }


      public function getAbsolutePath()
        {
            return null === $this->path
                ? null
                : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        public function getWebPath()
        {
            return null === $this->path
                ? null
                : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        protected function getUploadRootDir()
        {
            // the absolute directory path where uploaded
            // documents should be saved
            return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
        }

        protected function getUploadDir()
        {
            // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
            // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
            return 'uploads';
        }


        /**
         * Sets file.
         *
         * @param UploadedFile $file
         */
            public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
        {
            $this->file = $file;
        }


        /**
         * Get file.
         *
         * @return UploadedFile
         */
        public function getFile()
        {
            return $this->file;
        }

        public function upload()
    {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // use the original file name here but you should
        // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

        // move takes the target directory and then the
        // target filename to move to
        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName()
        );

        // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
        $this->path = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

        // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
        $this->file = null;
    }


        /**
         * Set path
         *
         * @param string $path
         * @return Article
         */
        public function setPath($path)
        {
            $this->path = $path;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get path
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getPath()
        {
            return $this->path;
        }



        /**
         * Set advert
         *
         * @param \test\MedBundle\Entity\Med $advert
         *
         * @return Apps
         */
        public function setAdvert(\test\MedBundle\Entity\Med $advert)
        {
            $this->advert = $advert;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get advert
         *
         * @return \test\MedBundle\Entity\Med
         */
        public function getAdvert()
        {
            return $this->advert;
        }

        /**
         * Set med
         *
         * @param \test\MedBundle\Entity\Med $med
         *
         * @return Apps
         */
        public function setMed(\test\MedBundle\Entity\Med $med = null)
        {
            $this->med = $med;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get med
         *
         * @return \test\MedBundle\Entity\Med
         */
        public function getMed()
        {
            return $this->med;
        }
        /**
         * Constructor
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->comment = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        }

        /**
         * Add comment
         *
         * @param \test\MedBundle\Entity\Affichage $comment
         *
         * @return Apps
         */
        public function addComment(\test\MedBundle\Entity\Affichage $comment)
        {
            $this->comment[] = $comment;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove comment
         *
         * @param \test\MedBundle\Entity\Affichage $comment
         */
        public function removeComment(\test\MedBundle\Entity\Affichage $comment)
        {
            $this->comment->removeElement($comment);
        }

        /**
         * Get comment
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
         */
        public function getComment()
        {
            return $this->comment;
        }

        /**
         * Set updatedAt
         *
         * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
         *
         * @return Apps
         */
        public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
        {
            $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get updatedAt
         *
         * @return \DateTime
         */
        public function getUpdatedAt()
        {
            return $this->updatedAt;
        }

        /**
         * Set unbrModif
         *
         * @param string $unbrModif
         *
         * @return Apps
         */
        public function setUnbrModif($unbrModif)
        {
            $this->unbr_modif = $unbrModif;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get unbrModif
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getUnbrModif()
        {
            return $this->unbr_modif;
        }
    }
```

code controller:

```
      public function addAction() {
          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $request = $this->getRequest();

          if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
          $x= $request->request->get('k');
            for( $i=1;$i<=$x;$i++){

          $nom = $request->request->get('nom'.$i);
          $prenom = $request->request->get('prenom'.$i);
          $age = $request->request->get('age'.$i);
          $class = $request->request->get('sexe'.$i);        
             $cop = new Apps();  
            $cop->setAge($age);
            $cop->setNom($nom);
            $cop->setPrenom($prenom);
            $cop->setClass($class);
            $cop->setPath("path test");
            $validator = $this->get('validator');
  $errors = $validator->validate($cop);

  if (count($errors) > 0) {
      /*
       * Uses a __toString method on the $errors variable which is a
       * ConstraintViolationList object. This gives us a nice string
       * for debugging.
       */
      $errorsString = (string) $errors;

      return new Response($errorsString);
  } else {

            $em->persist($cop);
            $em->flush();
            return new Response('Valide');
             }
           }
              } //end for

           return $this->render('MedBundle:Apps:form.html.twig');

          }
```

it displays errors but the problem now that the display of the errerue is not well here are example of **Validation Error Message**

> Object(test\MedBundle\Entity\Apps).nom: Cette champ existe déja. (code 23bd9dbf-6b9b-41cd-a99e-4844bcf3077f)

help me please and thank you

Comment: Can you try to describe it better? I (at least) am not understanding your description of the error :/

Comment: When he entered the data that exists in the database I have a validation error message that tells me that the Name field (for example) is exists in the database but the error that message

Object(test\MedBundle\Entity\Apps).nom: Cette champ existe déja. (code 23bd9dbf-6b9b-41cd-a99e-4844bcf3077f)

Comment: `* @UniqueEntity(fields={"nom","prenom","class","age"}, message="Cette champ existe déja.")`

I think the message is related to this, on the docblock at the top of your Apps entity.